# how to increase the size of text of ListBox using GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am using gwt ui binder for my application and trying to create a search box but I am not quite sure how to increase the size of text in the list box.

```
<g:FlowPanel styleName="{rscb.style.textAlignCenter}">    
   <g:InlineLabel ui:field="searchLabel" text="{labels.searchFor}" > </g:InlineLabel>
   <g:InlineLabel text="*" addStyleNames="{rscb.style.redStar}"></g:InlineLabel>
   <g:ListBox ui:field="searchListBox" styleName="{sccb.style.customerListText}" >
   </g:ListBox>
</g:FlowPanel>
   <g:SimplePanel addStyleNames="{rscb.style.textAlignCenter}">
   <g:Button ui:field="searchButton" text="{clabels.search}" styleName="{sccb.style.customerListText}"/>
   </g:SimplePanel>
```

What am I getting is 
[image]

What I am expecting is 
[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using css, something like this, (you might have to add to a child div or maybe this will work directly)

```
<g:FlowPanel styleName="{rscb.style.textAlignCenter}">    
   <g:InlineLabel ui:field="searchLabel" text="{labels.searchFor}" > </g:InlineLabel>
   <g:InlineLabel text="*" addStyleNames="{rscb.style.redStar}"></g:InlineLabel>
```

> ```
>    <g:ListBox ui:field="searchListBox" addStyleNames="myCss" >
> ```

```
   </g:ListBox>
</g:FlowPanel>
   <g:SimplePanel addStyleNames="{rscb.style.textAlignCenter}">
   <g:Button ui:field="searchButton" text="{clabels.search}" styleName="{sccb.style.customerListText}"/>
   </g:SimplePanel>
```

to your application css add this class

```
.myCss
{
    font-size : 2em;
}
```